# How to insert new column and leave all existing queries unchanged

Tags: sql, postgresql

We have very old and huge database with table **X** that is used almost everywhere. Lets say this table used for functionality **A**.

We are adding a new feature to the system that has to use table **X** in a new way. Lets name it functionality **B**.

So basically the new rows for new feature (**B**) has to be different to existing rows (**A**).

The main idea is to add new boolean column to table **X** that will be `FALSE` by default and `TRUE` for the new feature. But the prospect of changing `SELECT` and `UPDATE` queries across all system to add `WHERE new_bool_column = FALSE` condition, to support old functionality **A** makes us sad.

Is there any way in PostgreSQL to avoid this huge amount of work and make system to do it for us by setting up some special parameter somewhere? Do you have any other ideas of how it can be done easier, or completely different?

(we though about adding a View with the same name (and renaming the table **X**), but it will help only for `SELECT` queries)

Thanks for advance.

Comment: You might be able to use table inheritance to derive a new table from X.

Comment: imho  - that is just bad idea to expect records to be not the same kind. The way you've described the problem: I want to mix "apples" and "oranges". But imho that is exactly what you should try to avoid. So if you have "apples", use it for "apples", if you are about to create "oranges" - create new table for "oranges". but if they are the same kind: apples. So then your query should be ok : `SELECT * from apples` for old and new ones and `SELECT * FROM apples WHERE sub_kind='GOLDEN'` to get only new sub-kind introduced.

Comment: You should never use the same table for two completely different purposes. Could you explain it a bit more? If you have a new field with a boolean default value you should not need to update any existing scripts. You could try to handle that in a trigger in case you needed.

Comment: Are you willing to use a view? For example, you could create a new table Y and a view Z. Table X would remain the same. View Z would use `UNION ALL` for queries that need both X and Y.

Comment: Your proposed solution about renaming the table and making a view of the same name suggests that you have a lot of `SELECT *` happening. Perhaps bite the bullet and rewrite all of your UPDATE, INSERT, and SELECT statements to use this new column AND while you are in there, clean up your `SELECT *` to actually pull only the columns you need so you don't have to deal with this issue again. It sounds like some bad database design coupled with some not so great downstream logic is the real issue here, not your new column and new data.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your ideas and thoughts. i realized that learning how to use new things (like inheritance, Rules, etc) works requires time and adds more complication to the DB logic. This time can be used for simple query changing, so i'll choose it.